# How to access a camera that connected to a board via CSI

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, camera

I want to start writing code to play with a camera connected to a CSI interface, but I don't know where to start.

Assume that I have camera connected to a RPI via CSI interface.
How can I control the camera?
I know that there is a library for this, but I want to design my own camera board and then interface to it.

My questions are:

1. Is there any standard that I can use to setup a camera? I know that I can configure a camera via i2c bus, but each sensor has its own registers and sometimes it is very tricky to setup a sensor to capture or stream images successfully. Is there any such standard?
2. When the sensor was setup, and it streams data to a processor, how can I read them and convert bayer data to RGB images. I know how to convert bayer data to RGB in C/C++ (for example by using OpenCV), but I need a way to do it in hardware as it is too slow to so this in software.
3. Is the source for camera module of RPI available? I can read through it and understand how it setups camera and CSI interface of the ARM processor.
4. Is there any such document that documents how to use and setup CSI in ARM or Intel ATOM processors?